# "Unexpected $end" when using bash variables

Tags: bash, jq, string-interpolation

I've got a fairly simple bash script where I want to enable or disable a jq filter based on the value of an environment variable.

Here's a simplified version of the script:

```sh
JSON='{ "key1": { "name":"foo" }, "key2": { "name":"bar" } }'
OPTIONAL_FILTER=""
if [[ "$FLAG" == "value" ]]; then
    OPTIONAL_FILTER='| select(.key == "key2")'
fi
jq 'to_entries[] '${OPTIONAL_FILTER}' | .value.name' <<< $JSON
```

When I run the script with `FLAG=""`, then everything works as expected and I get the output:

```json
"foo"
"bar"
```

But if I set `FLAG="value"`, then I get the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
to_entries[] |
jq: 1 compile error
```

When I run the same commands in zsh, I do not get this error and I get the expected output of just `"foo"`

I am not very experienced in shell scripting. I'm guessing that there's a null character or some other input terminator like that being inserted into my string, but I haven't been able to confirm that or to find out a good alternative. It's especially vexing because it seems to be shell-specific. zsh, which I use for most of my testing, handles the code just fine. I only get that error when I attempt to run a `.sh` script that I see the error.

The ultimate goal is to get the optional filter working correctly. I am open to alternatives if there is a jq-specific option that I've missed. I tried using `jq 'to_entries[] $ENV.OPTIONAL_FILTER | .value.name' <<< $JSON`, but got `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting $end`

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulating program text by string interpolation is almost always best avoided if possible; fortunately, using jq, to my knowledge, it's always not only possible but also quite straightforward.

In the present case, you could for example use the --arg command-line option, like so:

```
jq --arg flag "$FLAG" '
  to_entries[]
  | if $flag == "value" then select(.key == "key2")
    else . end
  | .value.name' <<< $JSON
```

Comment: Oh, very nice. I had considered how I might use the arg option but the options that came to might weren't this elegant. The `else .` part didn't occur to me as a possibility. Tested and this is indeed a more satisfying solution. Not only that, but I can use use `#` comments in combination with the multiline single-quote string to better document that real query (which is significantly longer than the example)

Answer (score 4):

The way you're inserting `${OPTIONAL_FILTER}` is causing it to be split into multiple words, meaning `jq` receives more arguments than it's expecting. Bash interprets the command as if you'd written:

```
jq 'to_entries[] |' 'select(.key' '==' '"key2")' '| .value.name' <<< $JSON
```

You can quote it to ensure it remains a single word:

```
jq 'to_entries[] '"${OPTIONAL_FILTER}"' | .value.name' <<< $JSON
```

Or use double quotes throughout so you don't have to jump in and out of single quotes:

```
jq "to_entries[] ${OPTIONAL_FILTER} | .value.name" <<< $JSON
```

For more information see:

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Quoting Variables](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)